# Tile-based Game Engine or Framework for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, tiles

I'm planning to build a simple tile-based RTS (Real-Time Strategy) game for the iPhone and iPod touch.

Is there an existing game engine or framework that I could use? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: I have started writing my own map engine, built on cocos2d. Going well so far, but I'd still like to see another example or sample to refer to. There are a lot of design decisions that I'm making myself, which is fine, but I'm curious to know how others have done it (and maybe learn from their mistakes and so forth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a high-level engine dedicated to building tile-based RTS games that will run on the iPhone, but the iPhone port of cocos2d is great/easy for 2D games in general.  http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/

Comment: I'm already familiar with cocos2d - but (correct me if I'm wrong) none of the examples, samples or tutorials are overhead view tile-based.

Comment: Here is a tile-based tutorial for cocos2d that I found:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d

Comment: Kobold2D includes tilemap example projects both for orthogonal and isometric tilemaps. http://www.kobold2d.com

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2D is probably your best bet -- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Answer (score 1):

Define simple as far as the graphics and animation go... You may not need to bother with Cocos2D at all. If it is simple enough you could use both CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation along with CoreData and create your own engine. Being able to use the three together would simplify development as well as allow for the easiest way to manage and build additional functionality.

Would love to hear more - I might throw some code your way as well.

Ciao
Matthew

Comment: Well, it's a game, so performance is key. My experience with Core Graphics / Core Animation has shown that, in most cases, it's far slower than OpenGL (which cocos2d uses).

Comment: Check out or consider using Box2D and a level editor their is one by the cocos developer here: http://www.sapusmedia.com/levelsvg/ 
If you haven't already checked out inkscape that one might help too.
This will speed up development for you and you should be able to create custom methods from within them making development easier.

As far as performance make sure to see Apple's memory management doc: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html
Make sure to read the Garbage Collection Programming Guide.

-Matthew